# Add UIImage in a UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I'm beginner in Swift and I want to add an image to a custom path draw with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`. I show you my code:

```
let size = CGSize(width:newWidth , height:height)
let f = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
f.opaque = false
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size, format: f)
let im = r.image { _ in
    let leftUpPath = UIBezierPath()
    leftUpPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    leftUpPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadiusView, y: cornerRadiusView),
                      radius: cornerRadiusView,
                      startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2,
                      endAngle: .pi,
                      clockwise: false)
    leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
    leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: newWidth - cutPicture, y: height))
    leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: newWidth, y: 0))
    leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cutPicture, y: 0))
    UIColor(rgb : 0xffffff).setFill()
    leftUpPath.fill()
}
let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
iv.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
iv.clipsToBounds = true

let userPicture = UIImageView(image: picture)
userPicture.frame = iv.bounds
userPicture.clipsToBounds = true

iv.addSubview(userPicture)
cardView.addSubview(iv)
```

My custom path work well but when I add the `userPicture` the image take not the bounds of the path...

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want:

(replace the white background by the cat picture):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Care to add your current result as well as the expected result? :)

Comment: Clip to bounds only means that `UIImageView` will prevent the image from "overfilling" the view's bounds

Comment: @Glenn Done ! Replace the white bg by the cat picture is what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question with another solution (add the path to a shapeLayer and it to the mask of a `UIImageView`):

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadiusView, y: cornerRadiusView),
                radius: cornerRadiusView,
                startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2,
                endAngle: .pi,
                clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: newWidth - cutPicture, y: height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: newWidth, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cutPicture, y: 0))
    path.close()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = customShape.bounds
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    customShape.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
    customShape.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    customShape.image = userPicture
    customShape.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

final :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A subview's content always appears on top of the content of all of its ancestors. You make `userPicture` a subview of `iv`, so `userPicture`'s content appears on top of `iv`'s content. The content of `userPicture` is the cat picture. The content of `iv` is the purple frame. So the cat picture appears on top of the purple frame.

Instead, make `userPicture` the superview, and add a `frameView` subview to it containing the purple frame.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, when I make that, this is always the same, the picture overflow the `iv` path..